# Checkbox irregularities with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's some html:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-123" />
    <input type="text" id="text-123" onchange="doSomething('123')" />
</form>
```

And here's some javascript:

```
function doSomething(key)
{
    var textbox = $('#text-'+key);
    var checkbox = $('#check-'+key);
    checkbox.attr('checked',(textbox.val()!="") );
}
```

My goal here is to check the checkbox anytime there's a value in the text box, and uncheck when that value is removed.  This appears to work fine in the html (I can see `checked="checked"` being added to the checkbox), but the checkbox only appears checked the first time something is entered in the textbox.

Why would a checkbox show unchecked even if `checked="checked"` was added to the html?

Comment: If the listener calls "someFunction", why provide a function called "doSomething"? :-)

Comment: Because I like to keep people on their toes. =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use element properties rather than attributes to change their state via javascript

```
checkbox.prop('checked',(textbox.val()!="") );
```

From the jQuery docs on [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. **To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.**

The emphasis is jQuery's own. Only the checked **property** will reflect and control the checkbox's current state. The checked **attribute** shouldn't be used to control the checkbox state.

Comment: `prop` only takes 1 argument per the http://api.jquery.com/prop/ jQuery api.   did you mean something else?

Comment: @sircapsalot.. `getter` takes only 1 argument , but `setter` takes 2 arguments

Comment: Replacing `.attr` with `.prop` fixed the problem, and now I know what prop should actually be used for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen some funny things with the checked attribute in IE8 and lower.  In some cases I've had to set both the property and the attribute, even though modern browsers seem to be okay with just adjusting the property:

```
checkbox.prop('checked',textbox.val()!="");//property
```

Note, the following is only necessary if you come across any browser related inconsistencies.

```
if(textbox.val()!="") 
{
    checkbox.attr('checked','checked');
}
else
{
    checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
}
```

Comment: Just set the property, attributes are messed up in IE and behaviour isn't consistent across browsers.

Comment: @RobG - I agree that that should be the default.  I've added a clearer explanation

Answer (score 2):

consider something like:

```
function doSomething(el) {
    el.form['check-' + el.name.split('-')[1]].checked = !!el.value;
}


<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check-123">
    <input type="text" name="text-123" onchange="doSomething(this)">
</form>
```